# Phonegap : INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

Tags: database, cordova

While I am trying process one it's failing:

> Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 at file:///android_asset/www/library/custom.js:39

But when I am trying process two, its just fine.

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Pemberton", "1.0", "Pemberton Stay App", 200000);
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
```

Process 1:

```
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eat');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eat (id, image, title)');
    var queries = new Array();
    $.getJSON( serviceURL + 'category-list.php?cid=1&p=?', function(data) {
        var results = data.items;
        $.each(results,function(index,record){
            if( record.id != undefined )
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO eat (id, image, title) VALUES ("'+record.id+'","'+record.image+'","'+record.title+'")');
        });

    });    
}
```

Process 2:

```
function populateDB(tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO eat (id, image, title) VALUES (2,"one.jkd","OneFirst")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO eat (id, image, title) VALUES (2, "two.png","Second")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO eat (id, image, title) VALUES (3, "thr.png","Third")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO eat (id, image, title) VALUES (4, "fou.png","Fourth")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO eat (id, image, title) VALUES (5, "fiv.png","Fifth")');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db manipulation must be done after deviceready event see full example http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLTransaction

```
....
// Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }
....
```

Comment: Yes that is already maintained in my code. Is there any problem regarding the time taken to fetch the data from remote server? I am really confused.

Answer (score 2):

I've used .ajax() and solved this problem with adding ***async:false***;

> $.ajax({
>                           type: "POST", 
>                           url: myurl, 
>                           dataType: "xml", 
>                           **async : false,**
>                           success: function (xml) {
>
> ```
>                     $(xml).find('articles').each(
>                         function ()
>                         {
>
>                             tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ORDERS (id, client_ID, status) VALUES ('+ idord2 +', 4, "done" )');
>                         });         
>                     }
>                 });
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Although [one of the other answers works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265003/phonegap-invalid-state-err-dom-exception-11/12536659#12536659), I would like to expand upon it because I encountered the same problem and that answer doesn't say *why* it doesn't work as the OP had it.

When you create a transaction in Web SQL, the transaction processing remains alive only so long as [there are any statements queued up in the transaction](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#processing-model). As soon as the pipeline of statements in the transaction dries up, the engine closes (commits) the transaction. The idea is that when the `function(tx) { ... }` callback runs,

1. It executes all of the statements it need to. `executeSql` is asynchronous, so it returns immediately even though the statement has not yet been executed.
2. It returns control back to the Web SQL engine.

At this point the engine notices that there are statements queued up and runs them to completion before closing the transaction. In your case, what happens is this:

1. You call `executeSql` twice to queue up two statements.
2. You request something through ajax.
3. You return

The engine runs the two statements that it has queued up. The ajax request is also running asynchronously but it must access the network which is slow so it likely has not completed yet. At this point, the statement queue is empty and the Web SQL engine decides that it's time to commit and close the transaction! It has no way of knowing that there is going to be another statement coming later! By the time the ajax call returns and it attempts to execute the `INSERT INTO locations`, it's too late, the transaction is already closed.

There are two main solutions:

- Do everything (the `DROP`, the `CREATE`, and all the `INSERT`s) in one transaction inside the `getJSON` callback.

  This is what I recommend. I think it's very likely that waiting until after the ajax request completes before creating the table is compatible with your application requirements.
- Perform the ajax request synchronously as explained in the other answer.

  I don't recommend that. Asynchronous programming in JavaScript is a *good* thing.

By the way, while searching about this issue, I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953324/websql-transaction-wont-run-in-js-callback-functions/27167735) that basically has the same answer, so I wrote [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953324/websql-transaction-wont-run-in-js-callback-functions/27167735#27167735) but there is a little bit more detail over there. I know that copy & paste answer are discouraged on SO but I wanted to make sure future users consulting either question could read the answer. I made this one community wiki. I hope that's OK.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer.  Thanks for the details and the link to the processing model spec.